# Chat reputation in left bar seems different than any other reputation displayed for users

Tags: support, chat

I was just chatting on the Ask Different chat - and the reputation numbers for me and the others chatting don't seem to match any other reputation count I can see on the sites here.

Is there some calculation being made? These numbers are the highest of any other combined reputation I have seen. For me - I'm listed over 10k - but no other aggregate reputation counter I can see is above 8k.

Perhaps I'm unaware how reputation is calculated, but the people there suggested a bug report in case this isn't intended.

(after three lines of text are drawn - a number shows beneath our icons in the left hand side)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was confused by this as well, but I think I understand what's going on now.

The total score listed in your flair only includes sites where you're over 200 reputation. The chat total includes all sites you're on, including those where you have nothing more than the 100 reputation association bonus.

I just added up your reputation from all sites listed in your global profile, and it gave me 10,193, which matches up nicely with [your chat.SE profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/12928/bmike).

Comment: Cool - I'd love to know how you managed the math so fast. Multi tabbed browsing? Cool js script? wicked mental math skillz?

Comment: That would make sense - about 10 sites I rarely visit - meta and main, 100 rep each for having a profile. That's an easy 2k bump in no time.

Comment: @bmike I wish my mental math was that good. >_< I just scrolled down [your account listing](http://stackexchange.com/users/2c6a6773-56a3-45f2-b1bd-b31def1a6793?tab=accounts) adding them up using Google calculator through Chrome's address bar/omnibox.

Comment: Yes, this is a "global" rep count, that takes into account all accounts with more than 200 rep.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the flair shows just 7 SE sites, ordering them basing on the reputation, from the site with higher reputation, to the site with lower reputation; the total reputation is for those 7 sites (where your reputation is higher than 200).
What reported in chat is not the sum of your reputation in 7 sites.

For example, my flair says my reputation is 45K, but when I am in a chat room on chat.stackexchange.com, my reputation is shown as 48K.

Comment: Thank you! I guess it begs the question why not one or the other to use across the board.

Comment: The problem with the flair is the space it takes; if a user would be active in 15 SE sites, his flair would take more space than it does now. Imagine how it would be the Jeff Atwood's flair, if it would not show just 7 SE sites. `:-)`

Comment: I guess I don't see why the number has to reflect 7 sites on the flair. Sure - badge the top 7 sites, but shouldn't a point of rep be a point of reputation any way it's summed? Why calculate two sets of "combined" stats. I'm more interested in this as "inside baseball" - it's certainly not a big deal, just a head scratcher from where I sit and not someone that was here as each feature was hatched. I'm sure it made sense at the time (or still does looking at the back end code)

Comment: When I see a flair, I take the reputation is the total reputation of the SE sites shown in the flair. If my flair would show 48K, I would take that is the reputation I have on the 7 SE sites shown in the flair itself.